# XmlMediaTypeFormatter throwing <type> is not expected exception in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization, asp.net-mvc-5, mediatypeformatter

I'm writing a diagnostics website using MVC 5 that will make arbitrary requests to multiple backend services, reporting the results in either Json or XML in the browser.

Since the result types are numerous, I'm passing in a variable of type "object" to the Ok(content) method.

This is working fine when I'm requesting Json output, but is failing in the XmlMediaTypeFormatter when requesting xml output.  The exception is

```
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

The inner exception is

```
Type '<type>' with data contract name '<schema-address>' is not expected. 
Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically 
to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute 
attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to
DataContractSerializer.
```

This seems to happen with any return type that is not a simple pure object, e.g., a string return type will display properly, but even a simple class with 2 integer properties and 2 DateTime properties fails in this way. Digging into the code with the debugger shows that the call to HttpRequestMessage.CreateResponse knows what the type of the body-content is, and if try exercising it like [this link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization) says, it works just fine.

Googling this error leads to lots of discussions of Entity Framework navigation links and proxies, but none of that is applicable here since these are simple return classes with no EntityFramework or navigation references involved.

Does anyone have any leads?

Thanks.